# Python pandas column get rows with highest five numbers

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, max

I have a dataframe 'df1' with three columns: 'Name', 'Age', and 'Number' and more than hundreds of rows. I would like to create two new dataframes: 'df2' presenting 'Name' rows with the highest five 'Age' values and 'df3' presenting 'Name' rows with the highest five 'Number' values. I'm thinking doing some .sort() or .max() function but I'm not very sure. Can anyone help me with this please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: if not using the nlargest function, you could just as easily sort it then use iloc to slice the first 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the pandas `nlargest` function like follows:

```
df2 = df.nlargest(5, 'Age')
df3 = df.nlargest(5, 'Number')
```

Just make sure the columns are numeric type.